# Easy way to load custom javascript files on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, dependencies

I am working on a project where the Javascript is getting out of hand, so I've done my best to put each object into a different file (within reason of course... I sometimes group related objects and put them in one file if they are small).

One thing I am honestly having trouble with is managing the dependencies of these objects. Javascript doesn't seem to ways to include/declare dependencies... and I am honestly finding this really very annoying.

What's worse is that I have to put these dependencies into the separate html files which they are used. After including so many script tags at the bottom of so many pages, this has become an absolutely pain to manage. Here is an example:

```
<script src="${base}/js/ui/autoCompleteWidget.js"></script>
<script src="${base}/js/pagelet/addStudentToStudyGroupForm.js"></script>
<script src="${base}/js/pagelet/studentListing.js"></script>
<script src="${base}/js/pages/studyGroups.js"></script>
```

This is bad enough, because many of the first dependencies are declared over and over as they are needed on various pages. What is worse though is having to introduce 1 more dependency somewhere in the middle at a later point in time... and then having to go through my entire project and inject that one script tag over and over on each page where it is needed. Since there is no compile time warning on HTML markup... if I forget to do this on one page... the page simply won't work. Something like this is hard to automatically test and there's no way for me to know unless I check each page that uses Javascript.

I was wondering... what is easiest/most painless way to load these scripts? Like, what is the standard way to do it that robust, easy to do, etc.?

Thanks

Comment: How much JS are we talking about altogether? Is it so much that even minimizing it into one file would be too large of a file?

Comment: @DA: Well, I could do that, but I am unit testing these javascript files and I thought it would be appropriate to have a 1:1 ratio between the tests and the object that is being tested. I also want to say that eventually, there's going to be 30-40 big objects in the end. I'm legally blind... so putting all of this in one file actually makes things worse for me. I very much like an actual file-structure because I can use my IDE to pull up the right object quickly without scrolling and such.

Comment: I'd keep the files all separate on the dev side. Link to one JS file in your HTML and have that one JS file then load all of the rest. That way you always have the script you need on every page. Then as part of your deployment process, take all those files and run them through a minimize to combine and compress them all into one file for actual use online.

Comment: But with a java project and when running idea, I like to run my tomcat server straight from my sources... I don't want to have to go through some deployment process over and over. I already have a massive workflow as it is because of using an application server. That seems like more overhead :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into libraries such as http://requirejs.org/ which can take some of the pain out of this type of situation.

Comment: I've tried this solution. Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, when I give it a big list of dependencies... sometimes it works, and sometimes not. If I keep refreshing the page, it mostly works... but on occassion, jquery is not loaded as it should be... which causes the page to fail.